# How do I identify the colour of a pixel at the location of a mouse click in Firemonkey?

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, vcl

I have done something similar in VCL. I'm by no means a professional, and I do not expect this to be the best way to do it, but here's what I had:

```
pt := TImage(Sender).ScreenToClient(Mouse.CursorPos);
color := image1.Canvas.Pixels[pt.X, pt.Y];
```

I'm basically looking for some assistance in effectively porting this code into firemonkey, to get the same result, considering images/canvases etc. seem to work a little differently and I'm pretty unfamiliar with it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you need something like this:

```
procedure TForm1.Image1MouseDown(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton;
  Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Single);
var
  Cl: TAlphaColor;
  Dt: TBitmapData;
begin
  if Image1.Bitmap.Map(TMapAccess.maRead, Dt) then
  begin
    Cl:= Dt.GetPixel(Trunc(X), Trunc(Y));
    Image1.Bitmap.Unmap(Dt);
  end;
end;
```